# (jQuery) How do I add a function to an object even if it has not been created?

Tags: radio-button, jquery, radio-group

I have this script...

```
$.post('../script/php/getnumtreated', {
    medicalid: $('#medicalid').html(),
    numaffected: $('#numaffected').html()
}, function(data) {
    if (data == 1) {
        //Show #resolve radio button
    }
    else if (data == 0) {
        //Hide #resolve radio button
    }
});
```

The radio button group is initially shown, it has 2 radio buttons 'resolve' and 'not resolve'.

From my script the "data" must be equal to 1 before #resolve radio button has to show and 0 for the radio button to hide, but the radio button group only appears after a button is click.

'#add' button must be click first to create the radio button. The radio buttons comes from a separate PHP script.

How do I access those radio buttons even if #add has not yet been click?

I'm trying to do something similar to live()

Comment: You want to access the radio buttons before they exist? You can bind events onto selectors that will affect them after they are created but you cannot directly access them if they do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

did you try `$('#resolve').live('....',function()...` ??

Comment: What would I put in live('here', function(){});, #resolve has not yet been created?

Comment: yes this is why we use .live() u can add what function u would like. maybe this $('#resolve').live('click',function(){ /*your function here*/ }) and then when u #resolve has created it will has this click function.

Comment: I tried this                                       `$('#medstatus').live('click', function(){
var medicalid = $('#medicalid').html();
var numaffected = $('#numaffected').html();
$.post(
'../script/php/getnumtreated.php', {
medicalid: medicalid,
numaffected: numaffected
}, function(data){
if(data == 0){
$('input[name=medstatus][value=resolve]:radio').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
}
);
});` and it doesnt work. '#medstatus' is the name of the radio button group

Comment: Im not sure but maybe your post is wrong can u try to change like this ...{ "medicalid": medicalid, "numaffected":... and also add an alert after  if(data == 0) just for checking if it enter there

Answer (score 0):

```
isShowResolve = true;;
$.post('../script/php/getnumtreated', {
    medicalid: $('#medicalid').html(),
    numaffected: $('#numaffected').html()
}, function(data) {
    if (data == 1) {
        isShowResolve = false;
        showHideResolve()
    }
    else if (data == 0) {
        isShowResolve = true;
        showHideResolve();
    }
});
$("body").ajaxSuccess(function(){showHideResolve();});
function showHideResolve(){

   if($("#resolve").size()>0){
      if(isShowResolve)$("#resolve").show(); else $("#resolve").hide();
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi. What does `$('body').ajax(Success)` mean? Is it the same as `$(function(){});`.